# Middle-click cycles windows in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, synaptics-touchpad

I'm trying to get synthetic middle-click working in Firefox on a new HP G62 running Windows 7. (That is, I want to open a link in a new tab when I simultaneously press both touchpad buttons.) Originally, it wasn't working at all: clicking both fired both clicks. If I change my left button to middle-click in the Synaptics settings page or use http://cybernetnews.com/helpful-tip-middle-click-on-a-touchpad-laptop-mouse/ , then when I try to middle-click, Windows cycles my active window to the back.

I can't even find references to similar behavior; it's similar to Alt-Esc, but simply sends the foremost window under the cursor (and any, er, foremore windows not under the cursor) to the back of the stack.

I've tried adding `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Synaptics\SynTP\Defaults\HasBothButtonFeature` to my registry.

Sorry if I've asked this poorly; it's my first Stack Exchange question. Thanks to anyone who tries to tackle something so esoteric and vague.

Comment: I see the same behavior when using http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/06/01/hack-to-enable-two-fingers-scroll-gesture-to-replace-virtualing-on-synaptics-touchpad/  , so I'm reasonably sure that this really is my middle-click behavior for some reason.

Comment: You might look at this software, not sure if it will do what you want....http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [KatMouse](http://ehiti.de/katmouse/) feature.

> The prime purpose of the KatMouse utility is to enhance the
>   functionality of mice with a scroll wheel, offering 'universal'
>   scrolling: moving the mouse wheel will scroll the window directly
>   beneath the mouse cursor (not the one with the keyboard focus, which
>   is default on Windows OSes). This is a major increase in the
>   usefullness of the mouse wheel.
>
> Another feature involves the wheel button. Since the wheel button is
>   not consistently used in Windows, KatMouse can use it for a kind of
>   task switching: with a click of the wheel button you can push a window
>   to the buttom of the stack of windows that is your desktop, making a
>   recovered window the active window.

Comment: Retarded is a strong word. Don't insult yourself!

Comment: Wow, after all the struggle, it never occurred to me that another app would be responsible for this. Nice to know that it can be fixed. Cheers!